# Laravel order by specific column is equal id

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have table called points (id, name, with) columns, with column describe which point related to another point by id, what i need to select these data sorted by every point related to another by laravel elequant

```
id   name   with
 1    point1  3
 2    point2  6
 3    point3  1
 4    point4  5
 5    point5  4
 6    point6  2

$data = $this->model
        ->select('id', 'name', 'with')
        ->where('with', '!=', NULL)
        ->orderByRaw(DB::raw("FIELD('id', 'with')"));
```

I need something like that:

```
id   name   with
1    point1  3
3    point3  1
2    point2  6
6    point6  2
4    point4  5
5    point5  4
```

Comment: by which column u want to sort data ?

Comment: in pure SQL terms, try: `SELECT * FROM your_table_name ORDER BY LEAST(id, with), id`

Answer (score 0):

This should work as you want it to!

**EDITED**

```
$data = $this->model
        ->select(DB::raw('id, name, with, CONCAT( GREATEST(id,with) , LEAST(id,with)) as sortCrit' )
        ->whereNotNull('with')
        ->orderBy('sortCrit');
```

By the way, it's better if you don't  use "with" as a column name.

Comment: I also thought like this. but it will fail for `2,4` and `5,1` as both will give `6`

Comment: What about multiplication ?

Comment: aaa thanks dude, i understand now, i didn't see it at first, also multiplication will cause the same issue (4*4 = 8*2 ) ..etc

Comment: @NikleshRaut The edit should work fine i guess! since the concatenation should be always unique (bigvalue - small value)